# event handler hooking point and mobile safari highlight box

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, outline

I have a set of clickable divs inside a container div.
I want to handle the click event of all of them in a single handler on the container div.

however this causes mobile safari to highlight the the container div when one of the inner divs is clicked.

Is there a way to maintain the single event handler and yet tell it somehow what is the right child node to highlight?